# The Testflight does not update the build after it is assigned to testers

Tags: ios, react-native, app-store-connect, testflight

I recently ran into a issue that I don't understand. I have upgraded the version of my mobile project (20.3 - > 20.4). After that, I built the build using XCode and uploaded it. Then I waited until the build status changed to "Ready for submission" and assigned the build to the test team in Testflight.

Issue:

A messages about the availability of the build has been sent to testers, the build has the status "Waiting for Review", but the app has not been updated in the Testflight app and testers see the old build(20.3) =(

Comment: Is this version 20, build 4?  So you incremented the build but not the version?  Are these external testers?  Did you submit the new build for review in TestFlight in App Store connect?  Builds need to be submitted for TestFlight review and approved before they are available to external testers

Comment: @Paulw11 Agreed. Can you provide more information? Any new version you upload to TestFlight needs to be approved by Apple before it can be used by external testers. If your new build's status is "Waiting For Review",  your new build hasn't yet been approved by Apple for external testing.